# JavaScript issue in submiting form using submit handler

Tags: javascript, ajax, frontend

I had written below uses JavaScript for validation.

```
function runFormValidation() {

        $('#marge_product').validate({
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                console.log("inside submit handler");
                console.log("form"+form);
                $(form).ajaxSubmit(function(resp) {
                    $.widresetMSG = resp;
                    console.log("widresetMSG"+widresetMSG);
                    $.SmartMessageBox({
                        title: "<i class='fa fa-refresh' style='color:green'></i> Marge Product",
                        content: $.widresetMSG,
                        buttons: '[OK]'
                    });
                });

            },
            rules : {
                existing_sku : {
                    required : true
                }
            },
            messages : {
                existing_sku : {
                    required : 'Please enter existing sku'
                },
            },

            // Do not change code below
            errorPlacement : function(error, element) {
                error.insertAfter(element.parent());
            }
        });
        };`
```

here after successfully sumbitting the form it'll give me pop up box which contains response and that response will be shown in pop up box. But actually it's not working as expected. The response is showing on console as below

[image: here in console there is description of error]

controller side code :

```
@RequestMapping("/margeProduct")
@RequestMapping(value = "/margeParentProduct", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<String> getAllOrdersForDataTable(@RequestParam(value = "newsku") String sNewSku,
                                                       @RequestParam(value = "existingsku") String sExistingSku,
                                                                             HttpServletRequest request) {
    String message  = "Parent product marged successfully.";
    logger.debug("new SKU :" +sNewSku);
    logger.debug("existing SKU :" +sExistingSku);
    SupplierProductData supplierProductData = new SupplierProductData();
    Store store = CommonUtils.bigCommerceStore;
    ProductResource productResource = new ProductResource(store);

    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("sku", sExistingSku);

    List<Product> listProducts = productResource.getAllProducts(map);
    logger.debug("listProducts : " + listProducts.size());

    if(!listProducts.isEmpty()) {

    }else {
        logger.debug("Product is not exist on bigcommerce");
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Product with this sku does not exists on bigcommerce.");
    }

    return ResponseEntity.ok(message);
}
```

and `<form>` tag code:

```
<form id="marge_product" name="marge_product" class="smart-form" method="post" action="margeProduct/margeParentProduct" >

                                    <fieldset>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <section class="col col-4">
                                                <label class="label">New SKU :</label>
                                                <label class="input"> <i class="icon-prepend fa fa-user"></i>
                                                    <input type="text" name="newsku" id="newsku" placeholder="New SKU" value="${new_sku}" readonly>
                                                </label>
                                            </section>
                                            <section class="col col-4">
                                                <label class="label">Existing SKU</label>
                                                <label class="input"> <i class="icon-prepend fa fa-user"></i>
                                                    <input type="text" name="existingsku" id="existingsku" placeholder="Existing SKU">
                                                </label>
                                            </section>
                                        </div>
                                    </fieldset>

                                    <footer>
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                            Marge Prouct
                                        </button>
                                    </footer>
                                </form>
```

response pic:[image]
can any one suggest me what to do?

Comment: `console.log("form"+form);` this converts `form` to a string. Either remove `"form" +` or do `console.log("form:"); console.log(form)` as two separate instructions.

Comment: ok but that's not actual issue

Comment: actual issue is it's not showing pop up

Comment: I'd say the issue is that your server is responding with an error. Are you submitting the request in the way the server expects it?

Comment: Agree with @FedericoklezCulloca. The error code you're getting (400) means "Bad Request". In other words, the server didn't understand the request. Make sure you're submitting the request the way the server is expecting it.

Comment: ok let me try once again

Comment: i had tried once again but there is still same issue.

Comment: <form id="marge_product" name="marge_product" class="smart-form" method="post" action="margeProduct/margeParentProduct" >                                         is any thing wrong here?

Comment: ok, but is that what the server is expecting? We have no way of knowing, of course, but you should.

Comment: @RequestMapping(value = "/margeParentProduct", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody                    this is what i had mapped in my controller wich contains @RequestMapping("/margeProduct") i had opend that link wich sows 
"There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405).
Request method 'GET' not supported"

Comment: please don't put snippets of code in comments, it's unreadable. Put them in the question

Comment: i had attached snippets in question @FedericoklezCulloca please check again

Comment: The backend code is not enough. Please show the body of the method.

Comment: _(type=Method Not Allowed, status=405). Request method 'GET' not supported_ is pretty clear - now you got to figure out why your code does not send a POST request. Or maybe it does, but the server issues a redirect due to the URL not being a 100% correct maybe, and the browser then follows that by making a GET request.

Comment: ok, does the form have fields whith the `name`s as in the BE method's signature?

Comment: also, have you checked the actual content of the response? Because looking at the java code you may find part of your answer there

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca i had attechd from and also attached response screen shot please check

Comment: well, your answer is right there in the screenshot. if you think it's wrong check what gets sent to the service and then check the data in the db

Comment: uh pretty obvious from response that the issue is your server code is not finding whatever SKU its looking for...    uhhhmmm....   hmmmm.... yeah.